# RouteToRecipients Java DSL fails to send multiple messages to defaultOutputChannel

Tags: java, spring-integration, dsl, spring-java-config

I am a beginner in spring integration using Java Config and I am playing around with the following code:

```
@EnableIntegration
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder(org.springframework.integration.samples.si4demo.springone.h.testing.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run(args);
        System.out.println(ctx.getBean(org.springframework.integration.samples.si4demo.springone.h.testing.FooService.class).foo1("one two three four"));
        ctx.close();
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel="foo1")
    public interface FooService { String foo1(String request);}

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata poller() { return Pollers.fixedDelay(100).maxMessagesPerPoll(10).get();}

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel foo1() { return new DirectChannel(); }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel foo2() { return new QueueChannel(5);}

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel foo3() { return new QueueChannel(5);}

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel foo4() { return new QueueChannel(5);}

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel foo5() { return new QueueChannel(5);}

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(foo1()).split(e->e.delimiters(" ")).channel(foo2())
                .routeToRecipients(r->r.defaultOutputChannel(foo3()).
                        recipient("foo4","'one'==payload").
                        recipient("foo5","'two'==payload"))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean IntegrationFlow flow2()
    {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(foo3()).transform(String.class,s->s.toUpperCase())
                .get();
    }
}
```

I think that the output from the second integration flow should be THREE FOUR, but it outputs only THREE with the warning:

```
15:01:18.046 [task-scheduler-2] WARN  o.s.m.c.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel - Reply message received but the receiving thread has already received a reply:GenericMessage [payload=FOUR, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@7c343fee, sequenceNumber=4, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@7c343fee, sequenceSize=4, correlationId=6502c0da-c246-0c1a-64c2-211192c5248a, id=c26a054c-ab10-039e-d773-07457faf07f6, timestamp=1505822478046}]
```

Could please someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gateway pattern represents request/reply scenario - one request and one reply for it. That is exactly the same how we have only one `return` from Java method. So, the flow still sees `replyChannel` in the splitted messages, but that one has already been used and, therefore, we can't send more replies to the same request.

If you really consider to have `THREE FOUR` as a reply string, you should consider to use aggregator before sending to the `replyChannel` for the gateway.

Comment: Thank you Artem for your response. I added an aggregate EIP method to flow2(), and a .handle(System.out::println) before the get(), and there is not output now. Have you anything in mind?

Comment: Well, `.handle(System.out::println)` is one-way. There is definitely not going to happen reply. You should consider to use `.handle((p, h) -> {System.out.println(p); return p;})` or just `.log()`. The problem with `.aggregate()` that you need to have a proper `ReleaseStrategy`. Since not all your splitted item are going to reach `flow2`, you need some custom logic there.